# Return groupby columns as new dataframe in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Input: CSV with 5 columns.

Expected Output: Unique combinations of 'col1', 'col2', 'col3'.

**Sample Input:**

```
   col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 

0   A    B    C    11   30

1   A    B    C    52   10

2   B    C    A    15   14 

3   B    C    A     1   91
```

**Sample Expected Output:**

```
col1 col2 col3

A     B     C

B     C     A
```

Just expecting this as output. I don't need col4 and col5 in output. And also don't need any sum, count, mean etc. Tried using pandas to achieve this but no luck.

**My code:**

```
input_df = pd.read_csv("input.csv");

output_df = input_df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

This code is returning 'pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x0000000009134278'.
But I need dataframe like above. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can use `.drop()` to delete `col4` and `col5` as you said you don't need them.

```
df = df.drop(['col4', 'col5'], axis=1)
```

Then, you can use `.drop_duplicates()` to delete the duplicate `rows` in `col1`, `col2` and `col3`.

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
df
```

The output:

```
col1    col2    col3
0   A   B   C
2   B   C   A
```

You noticed that in the output the index is `0, 2` instead of `0,1`. To fix that you can do this:

```
df.index = range(len(df))
df
```

The output:

```
col1    col2    col3
0   A   B   C
1   B   C   A
```